# Writing categorial rasters with color and attribute symbology info in R

Tags: raster, r

I am generating landscape classification output rasters and adapted the code from WAF’s stackoverflow answer to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427787/write-classified-raster-with-its-symbology) to generate GeoTIFFs with embedded standardized color and attribute information.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

addColorTable <- function(inRstName, outRstName, rat.df){
  r<- readGDAL(inRstName)
  rat.df$color<- as.character(rat.df$color)
  rat.df$attribute<- as.character(rat.df$attribute)
  outRst <- writeGDAL(r, outRstName, type="Byte", 
                      colorTable=list(rat.df$color), 
                      catNames=list(rat.df$attribute), mvFlag=11L)
  return(raster(outRst))
}

# create dummy data set
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- 0
r[51:100] <- 1
r[3:6, 1:5] <- 2
r[1, 1] <- 3
writeRaster(r,'dummy_raster.tif',overwrite=T)

#create color and attribute table
# This defines the values, the color and the attribute
valT <- c(0,1,2,3)
colT <-  c("#FF0000", "#FF9900" ,"#99FF00","#0000FF")
attT <- c('Forest','Water body','City','Cropland')
rat.df <- data.frame(value=valT,color=colT,attribute=attT)

# apply the magic function
rnew <- addColorTable('dummy_raster.tif', 'dummy_raster_with_symbology.tif', rat.df)

plot(rnew)
```

[image]

The code works perfectly within R to generate the categorical land cover rasters with the proper colors (see figure above). However, no matter what I do, when I visualize the categorical raster outside of R (e.g., QGIS or ArcGIS) the raster legend includes legend elements for 0-255 raster values, even if my raster only has values between 0 and 3 (see figure below). Most importantly, element 11 in the legend is always displayed with a 0% opacity symbology despite nothing in my code specifying opacity.

Does anyone have any solutions to correctly save raster color and attribute info in R?

[image]
In the case above, the transparency of class 11 is not an issue because there are only 4 categorical classes, but in my actual classification rasters, my 11th class gets 'erased' as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way it has to be as the raster is encoded to 8 bit so, has 255 values. If you look at common landcover data, distributed with embedded color, (eg., NLCD *.img) you will see the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But what explains the weird 0% opacity of class 11? Every categorical raster with attribute table I export from r has this 'bug' in it...

Comment: Not sure what is going on with value 11. My first guess is that it is being assigned the NoData value but, this seems like an odd NA value. It is also difficult to identify this as an R, raster or GDAL issue. Have to tried to assign an explicit NA value to the 8-bit range (eg., 255=NA in the rat.df)?

Comment: Hmm... just realized that the opacity issue is only present when visualizing the data in qgis not arcgis.

Comment: in QGIS properties > symbology if you press classify only the four classes remain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work better with `terra`.

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.2.4
r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] <- 0
r[51:100] <- 1
r[3:6, 1:5] <- 2
r[1, 1] <- 3

coltab(r) <- c("#FF0000", "#FF9900" ,"#99FF00","#0000FF")
levels(r) <- c('Forest','Water body','City','Cropland')
x <- writeRaster(r, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
plot(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have been slowly transitioning to terra and it is incredibly fast and powerful. I am trying to get my colleagues to switch as well.